# Как правильно вписать конструкторы?

Tags: c++

Подскажите как добавить в класс стандартный и дополнительный конструкторы. В основной функции есть массив объектов, в который нужно добавить объекти которые сознаны в основном и дополнительном конструкторе и найти среднюю площадь и периметр.

```
    //Код файла  OverloadZ.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "solver.h"
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
{
    paralellogram one;
    double a, b;
    double d1, c, per, pl;
    cout << " First Side For Perumetr" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << " Second Side For Perumetr" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    per = one.perumetr(a, b);
    cout << " Enter side for ploza" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << " Enter height for ploza" << endl;
    cin >> d1;
    pl = one.ploza(c, d1);
    cout << "perumetr=" << per;
    cout << "ploza=" << pl;
    return 0;};

// Код файла  solver.h

#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
class paralellogram
{
private:

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d1;

public:

        int array1[10]; // объявляем целочисленный массив
    cout << "Enter elementi massiva: " << endl;
    int sum = 0;
    for ( int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++ ) // цикл для считывания чисел
        cin >> array1[counter];  // считываем вводимые с клавиатуры числа
    cout << "array1 = {";
    for ( int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++ ) // цикл для вывода элементов массива
        cout << array1[counter] << " ";  // выводим элементы массива на стандартное устройство вывода

double perumetr(double a, double b) // периметр 
    {
        double per = 2*(a + b) ;
        return per;
    }
    double ploza(double c, double d1) // площадь 
    {
        double pl = c * d1;
        return pl;
    }
};
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: Отформатируйте код. Условие тоже слабо понятно, попробуйте переписать, указав желаемый вход/выход